# Error in running sshd as a service in cygwin

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin, services, openssh

I am using cygwin run sshd. But now the sshd is not running as a service. When I start the service using 'net start sshd', Message comes like, "the cygwin sshd service could not be started.The service did not report an error. More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 3534" and if run using 'cygrunsrv -S sshd' the error comes like "Error starting a service. Query service status:win32 error 1062"

I have removed cygwin completely by deleting its services, server and registry. And installed again, but sshd is not running as a service.

can i have the solution for this?

Comment: try from an administrative cmd prompt if u havent already, and try `net stop sshd` before net start sshd.

Comment: and state how you removed "removed cygwin completely by deleting its services, server and registry".  And don't confuse Cygwin  with ssh within it.  Cygwin itself has no services. So state what deletions you made. as it may be of interest. But there's no need to remove cygwin to fix ssh. At most you'd want to remove ssh to reinstall ssh.

Answer (score 1):

#### Error starting a service. Query service status:win32 error 1062

> Sometimes you get a sshd/cygrunsrv service error after trying to run
>   the service.
>
> ```
> cygrunsrv: Error starting a service:
> QueryServiceStatus: Win32 error 1062:
> The service has not been started.
> ```
>
> There can be a couple of causes for this. The following may fix the
>   problem (this is not an option on XP Home).
>
> **Solution 1.**
>
> You may have an old or corrupt installation of Cygwin. Try
>   reinstalling.
>
> The following may also help:
>
> 1. `cygrunsrv -R sshd`
> 2. REBOOT (or use the Task Manager to kill all instances of sshd that may be running in the background)
> 3. run `ssh-host-config -y` again.
>
> This seemed to help on a few systems I worked on.
>
> **Solution 2.**
>
> Open an explorer window and use the "Properties | Security" dialog and
>   explicitly add "Full Control" for the SYSTEM user to the following
>   directories:
>
> ```
> C:\Cygwin
> C:\Cygwin\var
> C:\Cygwin\var\log
> ```

Source [Cygwin SSHD HowTo](http://www.noah.org/ssh/cygwin-sshd.html)

See also StackOverflow question [Unable to start cygwin sshd service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736096/unable-to-start-cygwin-sshd-service)

---

#### Further reading

- [Install Secure Shell Server (sshd) on Windows using Cygwin](http://www.larsavery.com/blog/how-to-install-sshd-secure-shell-server-on-windows-using-cygwin/)

Answer (score 0):

Checking `/var/log/sshd.log` `sshd` complained about `/var/empty` now owned by root (which is called "SYSTEM" on Windows).
The solution was to change the owner in an administrative Cygwin shell:

```
chown SYSTEM /var/empty
```

Comment: i don't know if you had the same error as the person asking the question.. but i do, and ssh server log file (in my case /var/log/cygsshd.log) , is empty